# Select sum count of last week

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have bellow snippet table.

[image: Table]

Here i have to fetch the top 3 `expert_id` of the last week which have completed `entry_status ="Completed"`

But i  am not getting idea how to fetch `expert_id` top 3 which have Completed status i am using bellow snippet code.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(count_set) 
   AS 'meta_sum' FROM wp_lead_action_records_date_status 
   WHERE 
   last_updated_date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
   AND last_updated_date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY 
   AND entry_status ='Completed' 
   AND entry_status ='Completed'") OR DIE(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo "Count sum " . $sql_chk_current_sum_count = $row['meta_sum']; 
  echo "<br>";
}
```

So any one have any idea how do do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
select count(*), expert_id from wp_lead_action_records_date_status 
where last_updated_date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
   AND last_updated_date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY 
   AND entry_status ='Completed' 
   AND entry_status ='Completed'
group by expert_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 3
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

The idea is that after filtering the rows with the where conditions, you group them by expert_id and then order them by count(*). limit 3 will return only the first 3.

Comment: how do i display count?

Comment: is the column count_set always equals to 1 ?

Comment: i have used select count(*) AS 'cnt' and echo $row['cnt']; is that right way ??? to display count

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Or you can just read the first column. The count that I suggested is correct only if the column count_set is always 1. Otherwise you need to use sum(count_set) instead.

Comment: count_set is always 1 then??

Comment: In this case it is correct what you are doing. Even though I think that it is not necessary to use the ' for cnt. I think it should be: select count(*) as cnt. I do not have a mysql instance to check so you have to check by yourself.

Comment: ok and last one question its showing result but from "which date - to date" it will show count from todays date.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: it first applies the where conditions, then the "group by" and then the order. So it will show the count for the rows that satisfy your where conditions.

Answer (score 0):

select count(distinct entrystatus) from tablename group by expert_id order by desc

i hope this will work